# Django passing parameter to CreateView and filling the form with it

Tags: python, django

I want to make a CreateView with the form already completed with an argument that will be passed to it from another view.

There is the initial view with an input field. Like this:

```
<form role="form" action="" method="post">
    {% csrf_token %}
    <div class="col-sm-6">
      <div class="form-group">
        <div class="form-line">
          <label>{{form.cpf.label}}</label><strong style="color:red;"> *</strong>
          {% if form.cpf.errors %}<label class="error">{% for error in form.cpf.errors %}{{error}}{% endfor %}</label>{% endif %}
          {{form.cpf}}
        </div>
      </div>
    </div>
    <button class="btn btn-success foot-btn" type="submit"><i style="vertical-align:middle" class="material-icons">add</i><span style="vertical-align:middle">Verificar</span></button>
</form>
```

When the user submits this form he will be redirected to another page. Asking if he wants to insert that value in the DB.

Right now I'm trying to redirect like this, trying to pass the POST value as a parameter to the CreateView

```
return redirect(reverse('blacklist:addcpfview', args=(request.POST['cpf'],)))
```

But I can't seem to get this parameter in the CreateView.

I know this I'm probably very wrong in the way I'm currently doing, but I'm a beginner with Django and want to know the best way to do this.

### UPDATE

The CreateView

```
class AdicionarCPFView(CreateView):
    form_class = CPFForm
    template_name = 'blacklist/cpf/addCPF.html'
    success_url = reverse_lazy('blacklist:cpfselectview')

    def get_context_data(self, **kwargs):
        context = super(CreateView, self).get_context_data(**kwargs)
        context['title_complete'] = 'Adicionar CPF'
        return context
```

Comment: try `def get_context_data(self, *args, **kwargs)`, your parameter is in the `*args` list. Better, use `kwargs` instead and give your parameter a name.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

As you use `CreateView` - it has a special method to fill initial values - [`get_initial`](http://ccbv.co.uk/projects/Django/1.11/django.views.generic.edit/CreateView/#get_initial)

What you need is to override this method and read variable from `kwargs` there.

```
def get_initial(self):
    initial = super().get_initial()
    # cpf - it's the name of the field on your current form
    # self.args will be filled from URL. I'd suggest to use named parameters
    # so you can access e.g. self.kwargs['cpf_initial']
    initial['cpf'] = self.args[0] 
    return initial
```

Another way to achieve this is to use session.

So when before you redirect you do `request.session['initial_cpf'] = request.POST['cpf]`
And in create view you access not `self.args` but `self.request.session`

And a side note - in first view it's a good practice not to read variable from POST, but use a form instead.

Comment: This error happened: get_initial() takes 1 positional argument but 2 were given

Comment: Try without `self`, I think I did a mistake with `super`. I updated my code snippet

Comment: It seems like its working. Thanks a lot! Just a question, is this the right way to do this? Or is there a better way to accomplish the same logic?

Comment: With current approach I'd rather use session, or GET Params, not URL. Also, There is a tool to run set of forms - http://django-formtools.readthedocs.io/en/latest/wizard.html Perhaps it will suits your needs. With it you can show fields split by steps, and use `done` method when you have all the data.

Comment: FormWizardView is a nice tool, but there will be some difference with existing code. E.g. initial val of CPF can be modified by user on 2nd form. With wizard the second form will be only "Save to DB" field, so it always uses CPF from first step. And also it depends on what validation do you have between first and second forms. If 2nd form is always shown - try to use wizard

Comment: Thanks a lot for the help man. I'll try to understand it better and implement it.

Comment: dude that link you posted is the holy grail. I have been looking all over the djangoprojects website for that resource and I can't find a complete API page that lists all the functions that can be overriden per type of Generic View